# Spring mongodb ajax badrequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to update article data vie ajax but I'm getting 400 (bad request) error. I think problem is with json but I cannot find where is actually the problem.

Article.class model

```
@Document
public class Artikal {

  public enum StatusZapisa {AKTIVAN, ARHIVIRAN}

  @Id
  private int sifra;
  private String naziv;
  @DBRef
  private KategorijaArtikla kategorija;
  private float cena;
  private int brojnoStanje;
  private Date datumKreiranjaZapisa;
  private boolean daLiPopunitiZalihe;
  private StatusZapisa statusZapisa;
  private int minimalnoStanje;
```

Article ajax files:

InventoryController.js

```
$scope.getAllArticles = function() {
    inventoryService.allArticles().then(
            function(data, textStatus, response){     
                $scope.articles = data;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("Failed to fetch all articles!", response);
            }
    );
}

$scope.fillTheStocks = function(article) {
    inventoryService.fillTheStocks(article).then(
            function(data, textStatus, response){     
                $scope.getAllArticles();
            },
            function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("Failed to refill article!", response);
            }
    );
}
```

InventoryService.js

```
this.fillTheStocks = function(article){
    console.log(article);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(article));
     return $.ajax({ url: "/SBZProjekat/api/article/fillTheStocks", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: JSON.stringify(article),
            contentType: "application/json"
            });
}
```

Spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api/article")
public class ArticleRestController {

  @Autowired
  private ArticleService articleService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/fillTheStocks", method = RequestMethod.POST,   produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<?> fillTheStocks(@RequestBody Artikal article)
  { 
     article.setBrojnoStanje(article.getMinimalnoStanje());
     articleService.saveArticle(article);

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
  }

}
```

I am getting this error in chrome console:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/SBZProjekat/api/article/fillTheStocks 400 (Bad Request)
Failed to refill article! Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Bad Request</body></html>", status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request"}
```

HTML function call:

```
<table class="col-lg-12 table table-hover">
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Akcija</th>
          <th>Razlog narudzbine</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="article in articles track by $index">
            <td>{{ article.sifra}}</td>
          <td>{{ article.naziv }}</td>
          <td>{{ article.kategorija.naziv }}</td>
          <td>{{ article.cena }}</td>
          <td>TODO akcija</td>
          <td data-ng-if="article.daLiPopunitiZalihe">Nedostaje {{ article.minimalnoStanje - article.brojnoStanje }} {{ article.naziv }}</td>
          <td data-ng-if="article.daLiPopunitiZalihe" class="clickable ta-mid" data-ng-click="fillTheStocks(article)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: green;"></span>
        </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please include the JS object you are posting.

Comment: @Veluria check now I added that part